# Why Should we assign a Http Attribute to every action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post, http-get

I having a question should we assign a http attribute for each action?
Like for example Index Page that doesn't have any action just displaying html we still need to assign a http attribute? Why since there is no retrieving data.
And If I remove Http Attribute for ViewDetail and CreateRecord, the page is still working and no bug what the huge difference for adding and not adding http attribute

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult ViewDetail()
        {
           //.... Get Data Action
           return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit","Home"));
        }

        [HttpPost]        
        public ActionResult CreateRecord()
        {
           //.... Create Action
           return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit","Home"));
        }
```

Comment: No, you don't need to use any http attributes at all if you have default endpoints  or routing. You need them only if you have several the same action routes and an mvc engine should have the way to figure which of them to use.

Comment: HttpAttribute, basically used for WebAPIs to build RESTful service and helps to define which HTTP method should be used to access to each method (GET, POST, PUT etc.). Request of Index page, by default, uses GET method.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some methods in your Controller class that are not HTTP Endpoints.